# How can I create launch screen in SwiftUI? I don't use storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create launch screen of my app using SwiftUI.

I've added new image in Assets and set this image name in plist file. I want to use it for all models of iPhones.
But my image has big size: 1600 * 2400 (.png).
When I launch the app I see my image, but it is out of the screen boundaries.
How can I diminish it?

Comment: This article gives an overview of what you can do with regard to the launch screen https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/launch-screen/

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! Yes, I had read this article before publishing my question. That example describes simple case, when developer uses background and logo only. Logo has a small size anyway. My case is about big background image. And I don't know how to set it.

Comment: Even though you're not using Storyboards in your app, you can use a Storyboard just for the launch screen. Setting the info.plist for the Launch Screen works, but it's much harder to customize. Here are the steps: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard/

Comment: Thanks. It works